# Truth Table For Switching Functions

Tags: truthtable

Can someone explain how these concept works?

I have 1 question. But I don't know have any ideas on constructing the truth table.

f(A,B,C) = AB + A’C

The answer given was ABC + ABC' + A'BC + A'B'C

And i have no idea how it get there. :-(

Comment: what you want ? understand from truth table or want to proof above expression.

Answer (score 1):

**1. Create a column for each of the inputs, each intermediate functions, and the final function:**

```
A B C | AB | A' | A'C | AB + A'C
--------------------------------
      |    |    |     |  
      |    |    |     |
      |    |    |     |
      |    |    |     |
      |    |    |     |
      |    |    |     |
      |    |    |     |
      |    |    |     |
```

**2. Enumerate all input possibilities, and start filling in the intermediate function values and then the final function value:**

```
A B C | AB | A' | A'C | AB + A'C
--------------------------------
0 0 0 | 0  | 1  | 0   | 0
0 0 1 |    |    |     |
0 1 0 |    |    |     |
0 1 1 |    |    |     |
1 0 0 |    |    |     |
1 0 1 |    |    |     |
1 1 0 |    |    |     |
1 1 1 |    |    |     |
```

**3. Now, you finish the truth table.**

### Update per OP's edit of question:

The "answer given" can be reduced as follows using Boolean Algebra:

```
ABC + ABC' + A'BC + A'B'C

AB(C + C') + A'C(B + B')

AB + A'C
```

...which is the same as the given f(A,B,C).   Not sure why `ABC + ABC' + A'BC + A'B'C` would be considered to be the "answer," but this does show equivalence between the two formulae.

Comment: you have a typo in your edit from the first to the second line, the second line should be `AB(C + C') + A'(BC + B'C)` which will lead to the third line `AB + A'C(B + B')` and then `AB + A'C`